# Is it possible for the c3js zoom function to zoom into the y values as well?

Tags: javascript, zooming, c3.js

Whenever I use the zoom in function on my c3js charts, only the x-axis and its values are zoomed in, while the y-values and axis stay constant. Is there a way to enable for the y-axis to also be zoomed into?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reset the values of the Y-axis.

Usage:

> zoom: {
>     rescale: true
>   }

Refer
http://c3js.org/reference.html#zoom-rescale